# Use regex to extract number before a list of words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to extract only the numbers before a list of specific words. Then put the extracted numbers in a new column.

The list of words is: `l = ["car", "truck", "van"]`. I only put singular form here, but it should also apply to plural.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["description"], data=[["have 3 cars"], ["a 1-car situation"], ["may be 2 trucks"]])
```

We can call the new column for extracted number `df["extracted_num"]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
l = ["car", "truck", "van"]

pat = f"(\d+)[\s-](?:{'|'.join(l)})"
df['extracted_num'] = df['description'].str.extract(pat)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(pat)
(\d+)[\s-](?:car|truck|van)

>>> df

         description extracted_num
0        have 3 cars             3
1  a 1-car situation             1
2    may be 2 trucks             2
```

Explanation:

- `(\d+)` - Matches one or more digits and captures the group;
- `[\s-]` - Matches a single space or hyphen;
- `(?:{'|'.join(l)})"`- Matches any word from the list `l` without capturing it.

Comment: One question, what does f"" mean here? I usually use r"".

Comment: @DanZimmerman It's an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#simple-syntax), a way to embed expressions inside strings which are evaluated at runtime. It's useful here to build a dynamic regex pattern based on the elements of the list `l`. The `r"` is used to build raw strings, which  treats backslash  as a literal character, not as a escape character.

Comment: Thank you Rodalm, I appreciate the detailed answer.