# How to extract number before specific strings in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["description"],
    data=[
        [
            "пластилин скульптурный гамма , торг.марк-гамма. производитель-ооо  россия. всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20 кор.на.поддоне 000 1 02"
        ],
        [
            "ел текстильныйtextile chalk, 3500 шт - вес: 6,4 кг, ; 2)1 коробки, ; 3) № конт.:dryu9183029, кол-во:1;"
        ],
        [
            "арт. 049231; точилка для карандашей (connect pastel 2h)pencil sharpener connect pastel 2h - 3200 шт.; произв.: good rise precision - вес: 114 кг, ; 2)10 коробок, ; 3) № конт.:mofu0672448(часть), кол-во:1;"
        ],
        [
            "пластилин скульптурный гамма , торг.марк-гамма. производитель-ооо россия. всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20 по 1000шт кор.на.поддоне 000 1 02"
        ],
    ],
)
```

I need to extract numbers before 'шт', 'кг', 'мл' or after 'вес:'.

The way it is written is rather different, could be like '100шт' or '6,4 кг. Also in some cases I have  'кг' appearing 2 times in a string ('всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20').
I am interested only when it comes after string 'вес'.

I found one code and reworked it a bit but it did not help me with some cases ([Use regex to extract number before a list of words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298502/use-regex-to-extract-number-before-a-list-of-words-in-pandas-dataframe)).

```py
l1 = ["шт", "шт.", "шт:"]
l2 = ["кг", "кг,", "кг;"]
l3 = ["мл:", "мл.", "мл"]
pat1 = f"(\d+)[\s-](?:{'|'.join(l1)})"
dfs["шт"] = dfs["description"].str.extract(pat1)  # extracts number before string
pat2 = f"(\d+(?:{'|'.join(l1)}))"
dfs["шт2"] = dfs["description"].str.extract(pat2)
# extracts number before string if it is'23шт'
dfs["шт2"] = dfs["шт2"].str.extract(
    "(\d+)", expand=False
)  # gets just a number from '23шт'
pat3 = f"(\d+[.,]*\d*[.,]*\d*)[\s-](?:{'|'.join(l2)})"
dfs["кг"] = dfs["description"].str.extract(pat3)  #
```

Please help to make my code more concise as df is rather big and need to a help to deal with all cases like '6,4 кг' and '100шт'.

Expected output in a separate column is '6,4 кг' -> '6,4 and '100шт'->'100' as well as 96,9 and not 1 in 'всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and Python standard library's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```py
import re

for term in ["шт", "мл"]:
    df[term] = (
        df["description"]
        .apply(
            lambda x: [
                m.replace(" ", "").replace(term, "")
                for m in re.findall(rf"\d+[,]?\d*\s?[{term}]{{2}}", x)
            ]
        )
        .apply(lambda x: x if len(x) > 0 else pd.NA)
    )

df["кг"] = df["description"].apply(lambda x: x.split("вес: ")[-1].split("кг")[0])
```

Then:

```py
0                                                         пластилин скульптурный гамма , торг.марк-гамма. производитель-ооо  россия. всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20 кор.на.поддоне 000 1 02   
1                                                                                                        ел текстильныйtextile chalk, 3500 шт - вес: 6,4 кг, ; 2)1 коробки, ; 3) № конт.:dryu9183029, кол-во:1;   
2  арт. 049231; точилка для карандашей (connect pastel 2h)pencil sharpener connect pastel 2h - 3200 шт.; произв.: good rise precision - вес: 114 кг, ; 2)10 коробок, ; 3) № конт.:mofu0672448(часть), кол-во:1;   
3                                                пластилин скульптурный гамма , торг.марк-гамма. производитель-ооо россия. всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20 по 1000шт кор.на.поддоне 000 1 02   

            шт    мл     кг  
0        [100]  <NA>  96,9   
1       [3500]  <NA>   6,4   
2       [3200]  <NA>   114   
3  [100, 1000]  <NA>  96,9
```

Comment: How about cases when i have data=[ "пластилин скульптурный гамма , торг.марк-гамма. производитель-ооо  россия. всего: по 1 кг, 100шт. в 20 кор. - вес: 96,9 кг 20 по 
 1000шт кор.на.поддоне 000 1 02"]  I mean I have 2 occurances of number before 'шт'? 
I need both

Comment: Hi, I've added these use cases to your post and updated my answer to deal with them. Cheers.